# No Subtitle field in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios11

When editing my app info, I do not see a field to set the new "Subtitle" text for the iOS 11 AppStore.
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/product-page

When I view my app on the iOS 11 AppStore, my developer name displays in the area used to show the Subtitle text.

I have an "Individual" developer account, so the developer name is my name "Michael Peterson". I'd much rather put some custom text into the Subtitle area but I cannot find the field anywhere in the iTunes Connect app edit screen.

Does anyone know if the Subtitle text field is limited to "Organization" developer account, or is there something else I am missing or not seeing that would enable me to set custom text for the Subtitle?

[image: Documention]
[image: My app in iOS 11 AppStore]

Comment: Should be available under App Information in iTunes Connect. It's below your app name in the Localizable Info section, both my personal account and organization show the field so seems like that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Ah! I didn't look there - I expected to be in the main app info section. Thanks! If you post this as an Answer I'd upvote/accept it.

Comment: Done, you can accept the answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be available under App Information in iTunes Connect. It's below your app name in the Localizable Info section, both my personal account and organization show the field so seems like that shouldn't matter.